# Plot map of a city without google map API in r

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to visualise Chicago in R. It seems I have some issues with google API which I didn't manage to resolve, following several advice from stackoverflow.

Is there a way to plot the city without using google services? I just need a very coarse-detailed map.

Thanks.

Comment: You can look for `r-leaflet`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of `ggmap`'s built-in functions to query different map services, e.g. Stamen:

```
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
library(ggmap)
chicago <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left = -88.0225, bottom = 41.5949, 
                                  right = -87.2713, top = 42.0677), 
                         zoom = 11)

ggmap(chicago)
```

This uses the development version of the package because, as the package author notes on GitHub, the CRAN version is outdated.

Depending on your needs, you may want to play around with the bounding box, the zoom level and even the map type (see `?get_stamenmap` for more details).